# what is the relationship between LCS and string similarity?

Tags: algorithm

I wanted to know how similar where two strings and I found a tool in the following page:
https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/string_similarity/

and it says that this tool is based on the article:

"An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations"

available on: 
http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf

I have read the article, but I have some doubts about how they programmed that tool, for example the authors said that it is based on the C library GNU diff and analyze.c; maybe it refers to this:

https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/

and this:
https://github.com/masukomi/dwdiff-annotated/blob/master/src/diff/analyze.c

The problem that I have is how to understand the relation with the article, for what I read the article shows an algorithm for finding the LCS (longest common subsequence) between a pair of strings, so they use a modification of the dynamic programming algorithm used for solving this problem. The modification is the use of the shortest path algorithm to find the LCS that has the minimum number of modifications.

At this point I am lost, because I do not know how the authors of the tool I first mentioned used the LCS for finding how similar are two sequences. Also the have put a limit value of 0.4, what does that mean? can anybody help me with this? or have I misunderstood that article?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the description on the string similarity tool is not being entirely honest, because I'm pretty sure it has been implemented using the Perl module [String::Similarity](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Similarity/Similarity.pm). The similarity score is normalised to a value between 0 and 1, and as the module page describes, the limit value can be used to abort the comparison early if the similarity falls below it.

If you download the Perl module and expand it, you can read the C source of the algorithm, in the file called fstrcmp.c, which says that it is "Derived from GNU diff 2.7, analyze.c et al.".

The connection between the LCS and string similarity is simply that those characters that are *not* in the LCS are precisely the characters you would need to add, delete or substitute in order to convert the first string to the second, and the number of these differing characters is usually used as the difference score, as in the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).